# How to implement scrolling content widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example website is http://www.wikihow.com/Main-Page, check the "Recent Changes" heading on the right side.

I am really amazed with the implementation of such scroll bars.
Google also uses something very similar to this.

Can someone give me some idea how to do this using jquery.

Comment: I had to move the link from title to body, couldn't click it! That's a very nice widget indeed, someone should consider making a jquery plugin out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use [JSONP](http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html) (JSON with padding). When the page is loaded they reference the following url: http://pad1.whstatic.com/Special:RCWidget?function=rcwOnLoadData which sends JSON data wrapped in a function. All that is left is the `rcwOnLoadData` to loop through the data using [setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/) and show it in a target div. An important note is that they do not use AJAX, all the data is pushed to the client at page load time.

Comment: Any idea where can i get access to a more detailed instructions for implementation ?

Comment: You mean, someone writing the code for you or you have specific questions about implementing JSONP on the server side, client side?

Comment: Terribly late sorry, I want to learn implementing one from scratch. Can you guide me ?